# What was the previous version of an package?

Tags: apt, 20.04

I've been trying to work out an issue I've encountered today with Ubuntu and noticed that an unattended upgrade had occurred throughout the day. How can I see a history of what version a particular package was prior to an update?

Comment: Actions with  `apt-get` logged can be accessed by`less /var/log/apt/history.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `apt changelog <packagename>`.

Newer packages are at the top.

Here's an example of the `hello` package changelog on Ubuntu 20.10.

You can see that the version number and upload date are clearly shown for each upload.

```
hello (2.10-2ubuntu2) eoan; urgency=medium

  * Handle exit code 77 for skipped autopkgtests.

 -- Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 22 May 2019 21:53:15 -0700

hello (2.10-2ubuntu1) eoan; urgency=low

  * Merge from Debian unstable.  Remaining changes:
    - Run the upstream tests as an autopkg test as well.
  * Dropped changes, included in Debian:
    - Bump the standards version.

 -- Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 22 May 2019 16:36:23 -0700

hello (2.10-2) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Fix version skew. Closes: #928887.
  * Drop debian/compat and use new syntax to specify compat level.
  * Standards-Version: 4.3.0 (no changes for this).
  * Rules-Requires-Root: no

 -- Santiago Vila <sanvila@debian.org>  Mon, 13 May 2019 20:06:50 +0200
```